# 'You do not have access to the app set.' when doing jhipster:heroku

Tags: java, jhipster, heroku-toolbelt

I have a projet on a repository on bitbucket (git).
This is a jhipster project.
I want to put online my application on heroku but I have an error while executing this command:

```
yo jhipster:heroku
```

The error is this one:

```
Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "mvn package -Pprod -DskipTests=true && heroku deploy:jar --jar target/*.war --app set git r"
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
 !    You do not have access to the app set.
```

I tried different things:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and

```
git remote rename set production
```

with error for 2nd command:

```
error: Could not rename config section 'remote.set' to 'remote.production'
```

any ideas?

Comment: I also tried with this command but same error:
heroku apps:rename newname